# Grouping BY Same Fields and Showing As 1 Division

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a collection returning messages, however, I want to group them by 'subjects' and 'sender' to create 1 div for each subject, and show the latest one's created_at.

So I have:

`id | senderId | receiverId | subject | message | created_at`

My Controller:

```
 $messages = Message::where('receiverId', \Auth::user()->name)
                 ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                 ->paginate(10); 

  return view('chat')->with(compact('messages'));
```

So this works: `dd($messages[0]->subject)`. Also, in my view, I can use `@foreach` to use it as `$message->created_at`. Currently it seems like this (subjects are not listed):

*yIZgT0oqH - is name

[image]

How can I group them by `subject` and `senderId`, and show them as 1 group(1 div) by using the latest message (`created_at`)? What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your query to do something like this, using `groupBy` / aggregation.

```
$messages = Message::where('receiverId', \Auth::user()->name)
                 ->groupBy('subject')
                 ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                 ->paginate(10);
```

Check the documentation for the same - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. For more detailed discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271715/laravel-5-multi-dimensional-groupby-orderby-paginate