# Laravel 5 - multi-dimensional groupBy, orderBy & paginate

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination

I have a Post model and I am trying to `->paginate()`, `->groupBy()` and `->orderBy()`.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::where('verified', '1')
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->groupBy('topic', 'publisher_id')
            ->paginate(5);

    // dd($posts);
}
```

Meanwhile, data in Database looks like this:

```
|  id  |  verified  |  topic  | publisher_id |  body  | created_at |
|  25  |      1     |  Forest |       3      |   EE   |  10.12.50  |
|  24  |      1     |  Forest |       3      |   DD   |  10.11.40  |
|  23  |      1     |  Forest |       3      |   CC   |  10.10.30  |

|  22  |      1     |  Dance  |       2      |   BB   |   9.50.50  |
|  21  |      1     |  Dance  |       2      |   AA   |   9.40.40  |

|  20  |      1     |  Music  |       1      |   ZZ   |   9.30.30  |
|  19  |      1     |  Music  |       1      |   XX   |   9.20.20  |
|  18  |      1     |   Art   |       1      |   YY   |   9.10.10  |
|  17  |      1     |   Art   |       1      |   WW   |   9.00.00  |

|  16  |      1     |   Ski   |       2      |   KK   |   7.00.00  |
```

When I uncomment the the `dd()` and run the code, I get this log:

```
 LengthAwarePaginator {
                       ...
                      items : {
                           items : {
                                   0 => Post{..}
                                   1 => Post{..}
                                   2 => Post{..}
                                   3 => Post{..}
                                     ...
                                   }
                              }
                        ...
                       }
```

> `0 => Post{#249} : "published_by: "3", "body": "CC", "created_at": "10.10.30"`
>
> `1 => Post{#250} : "published_by: "1", "body": "XX", "created_at": "9.20.20"`
>
> `2 => Post{#251} : "published_by: "1", "body": "WW", "created_at": "9.00.00"`
>
> `3 => Post{#252} : "published_by: "2", "body": "KK", "created_at": "7.00.00"`

It looks so weird for a reason. It did `groupBy` for user-3, but not for others. Also, it's pulling the earliest created at rather than latest. Changing `desc` to `asc` like `->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`would put everything completely out of track.

In other words, **returning `'CC' for user-3, Forest` instead of `'EE' for user-3, Forest`**

Then I thought maybe it's the `->paginate(5)` messing things up.

```
public function post()
{
    $posts = Post::where...
                        ...
            ->paginate(5);

    $postsTry = Post::where('verified', '1')
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->groupBy('topic', 'publisher_id')
            ->get();
    
     // dd($postsTry);
 }
```

I get a Collection with only the `items` like above object in it.
(`0 => Post{..}, 1 => Post{..}, 2 => Post{..}`).

**It's grouping data as being *earliest first* rather than *latest first*.** What I am missing? What is the thing I am doing wrong?

---

> To wrap up, **note that what I want to get is:**
>
> `'EE' for user-3, Forest`
>
> `'BB' for user-2, Dance`
>
> `'ZZ' for user-1, Music`
>
> `'YY' for user-1, Art`

Comment: Could you post the result of `$posts->toSql();` ?

Comment: "select * from `posts` where `verified` = `1` group by `topic`, `publisher_id` order by `created_at` desc". When I try after `->paginate(5)->toSql();` it throws an error, so I added after `->groupBy()`

Comment: The GroupBy is working as expected, it is grouping by `publisher_id` **AND** `topic`. As records with publisher_id 1 and 2 cover multiple topics, you will end up with multiple records (a record for each unique topic that exists).

Comment: So, is the logic completely wrong? What I want to do is only return `EE` for `user-3, Forest` , `BB for user-2, Dance` etc.. Combining same user_ids & same subjects. But instead, it's returning `CC` for `user-3, Forest`

Comment: Swap the location of `orderBy` and `groupBy`: `Post::wher('verified', '1')->groupBy('topic', 'publisher_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(5)`

Comment: @aldrin27 I tried your combination, but same result. `'CC' for user-3, Forest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Removed my previous answer* but will still include the note from [Laravel Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination) about chaining `groupBy()` with `paginate()`.

> Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a `groupBy` statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a `groupBy` with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

**UPDATE**

Due to your unusual date format for the `created_at` field, you'll need integer `cast`ed values for it to used by the `order by` statement properly (as an integer, not a string). Here's a working example:

```php
Post::selectRaw("*, CAST(REPLACE(created_at, '.', '') AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) ca")
    ->where('verified', '1')
    ->orderBy('ca', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('topic', 'publisher_id')
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: Since pagination simply uses `LIMIT ?,?` when running queries, it still works. It's just not __efficient__ because SQL has to run the `GROUP BY` on all records before it can limit the results. But that's the case in any group by situation and you can only really just add conditions to decrease your pre-group result set to try and optimize. Also this isn't the issue he's dealing with. He's trying to get the row with the latest date for each matched group as the grouped row.

Comment: @DavidBoskovic thank's for pointing that out. I just updated my answer. But anyhow, it's still discouraged to chain `groupBy()` and `paginate()`.

Comment: @SandyandiN.delaCruz I tried adding your example `selectRaw("*, CAST(REPLACE(created_at, '.', '') AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) ca")`, but still getting the same result `'CC' for user-3, Forest`. I've been working on it but still couldn't figure out why. What's is the (most efficient) way to do it? How can I achieve `'EE' for user-3, Forest`, `'BB' for user-2, Dance` etc..?

Comment: Did you `orderBy('ca',  'desc')`? I tried it with the data you have and I got EE for user#3.

Comment: First, I forgot to changed `created_at, 'desc'` to `'ca'` and I was getting the result in my last comment. Now, I edited it, but for some reason, as the `[0] => Post`, I am getting the first data (id=1 `id(auto increment)`) for some reason. :S Why mine is behaving different..? May it be related with the number in the pagination (`->paginate(#)`)? Also, I have just realised that I can use auto-incremented `id` instead of `created_at` and these still should pass the same data, no? But, this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a subquery (or another join method) to get the top item in your group. See [Getting The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

*Removed my example.*

Comment: `Call to a member function orderBy() on string`

Comment: Adding `->addSelect(DB::raw('MAX(`created_at`) as `created_at`'))` is causing only `created_at` field to be selected and returned in the collection. `items { items { 0 => Post { #1 attribute } 1 => Post { #1 attribute } ... } `

Comment: try `->select('*',DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as created_at'))`

Comment: Now, it's selecting everything, but with the same created_at order (earliest first).

Comment: "select *, MAX(created_at) as created_at from `posts` where `verified` = `1` group by `topic`, `publisher_id` order by `created_at` desc" and it's still returning `'CC' for 0 = > Post { }`

Comment: I tried your last edit, it's returning the ones I select successfully, but still returning `'CC' for 0 = > Post { }` :/ instead of `EE`